# nginx load balancer traffic

Tags: nginx, migration

Hello currently i am having 4 nginx load balancer machine in aws, all of them is using Elastic IP address, and all of them is registered under a domain name test.com. i am planning to rebuild the new nginx load balancer and reattach the EIP to the new nginx load balancer machine. let say i have lb01,lb02,lb03,lb04 the old one and newlb01, newlb02,newlb03, newlb04 the new one, then i want to reattach the EIP from lb01 to newlb01. My question is what would happen to the request that still processed on lb01? how should i handle or migrate them safely?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually EIP works instantly but if you have a request underprocess while you move EIP to another server the request will not break because at that time LB has to return the request not accept new one . the Load balancer will be up with outgoing internet connection and your user will get the response back with out downtime.

and instantly new requests will to the new LB as you have changed the EIP .

Note that EIP is not cached like DNS , so dont need to worry .. this is the one purpose of EIP to avoid downtime even for milli seconds.

BUT: If you shutdown the LB (Dont do this unless you test new LB heavily) than your existing requests will break ..

Comment: hm okay thankyou for the answer zee, now i can safely proceed the migration